# Deploying a sailsjs application to openshift, error with sails-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, openshift, sails-mongo

I am trying to deploy my application to openshift. I followed the [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment/hosting) on the sailsjs website. When I entered `git push` I got an error saying it failed to deploy the application so I ran `rhc tail nodejs`, and I got the following log.

[image]

I configured the `connections.js` as follows

```
someMongodbServer: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST,
port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT,
user: 'admin',
password: '<thepassword>',
database: 'myappdatabase'
},
```